# MYSQL: join key different from zero

Tags: mysql

Having these two tables:

Offer:

-id

-title

-id_sector1

-id_sector2

(these two last one, are foreign key from the following table)

Sector:

-id

-name

I would like to select data from offer table, with double join.

```
SELECT offer.id
     , title
     , subtitle
     , description
     , identifier
     , coins
     , expiration_date
     , image_normal_url as image
     , image_mini_url as image_mini
     , sect1.name as 'sector1'
     , sect2.name as 'sector2'
     , cat.name as 'category'
     , sect3.name as 'suggested1'
     , sect4.name as 'suggested2'
     , zones_str as textzone
     , telephone
     , whatsappnumber
     , whatsapptext
     , fblink
     , chat
     , ChCustSource
  FROM offer
  LEFT 
  JOIN sector as sect1 
    ON sect1.id = offer.id_sector1
  LEFT 
  JOIN sector as sect2 
    ON sect2.id = offer.id_sector2 
   AND offer.id_sector2 is not null
  JOIN category as cat 
    ON cat.id = offer.id_category
  LEFT 
  JOIN sector as sect3 
    ON sect3.id = offer.id_suggested1
  LEFT 
  JOIN sector as sect4 
    ON sect4.id = offer.id_suggested2
 ORDER 
    BY offer.timestamp asc
```

The second, on "id_sector2" don't select records having "id_sector2" equal to zero in offer table (because of course, it won't be found any "sect2.id" equal to zero). I would like to make it optional, I've tried with:

```
left join sector as sect2 on sect2.id=offer.id_sector2 and not(offer.id_sector2 <=>0)
```

Moreover with:

```
left join sector as sect2 on sect2.id=offer.id_sector2 and offer.id_sector2 !=0
```

But still doesn't work.
I get only rows from "offer" table having "id_sector2" different from zero.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Since it's a LEFT JOIN, all rows from `offer` table should be "selected". So your problem is not clear.

Comment: They are selected, but there's the column "sector2" that can be equal to zero. This means that won't be found any row on "sector" table with "id" equal to zero.
In fact, if I remove that clause, I'll see all rows from offer table.

Comment: what are the current results and desired results?

Comment: The result is composed by ALL rows contained in "offer" table excepted for rows having "id_sector2" column field equal to zero.

Comment: @LorenzoN. I don't know what you are talking about. No offer is removed by the ON clause - see example here: http://rextester.com/OAYVY54060

Comment: I've seen and still not found a solution about these records that aren't shown.
https://ibb.co/kKK5BG

Answer (score 0):

if you want actual sector 2 WITH EXCLUSION OF the ID = 0, change

```
JOIN sector as sect2 
    ON sect2.id = offer.id_sector2 
   AND offer.id_sector2 is not null
```

to

```
LEFT JOIN sector as sect2 
    ON offer.id_sector2 = sect2.id
   AND offer.id_sector2 > 0
```

This way, you are always staying on the LEFT-JOIN qualifier, but if and only if the sector IDs match AND the original Offer table has a sector 2 ID GREATER than 0.  So the original offer will still qualify, but it will only find the match in sector 2 when the ID is other than 0.

**CLARIFICATION**

Ok, I THINK I get what you want...  You have a bunch of records in the first table that link to your Sectors table.  Not all records will have a sector 2 hence a left-join if not required.  Additionally, some records may have a sector2 ID of zero (assuming that the ID=0 in your lookup table actually exists).  If any are of ID = zero, you do not even want to see the Offer record, almost like you want it hidden.

If this SOUNDS accurate, I would do the following...

```
LEFT JOIN sector as sect2 
    ON offer.id_sector2 = sect2.id
```

AND THEN, in your WHERE clause, do the following..

```
WHERE
      sect.id IS NULL
   OR sect.id > 0
```

Does this get what you want?

Comment: It is the main problem I've encountered. I would like to INCLUDE the rows having ALSO id_sector2 equal to zero!

Comment: Is what have I written in my question.

Making up a left join without any clause, don't output rows with id_sector2=0

Comment: @LorenzoN., see revised clarification in my answer.

Comment: It doesn't still work. 
I have no records on table "sector" having the primary key equal to zero, instead I have records on table "offer" with id_sector2 equal to zero.
I don't know why, but will be returned all record excepted for these: ibb.co/kKK5BG

Comment: @LorenzoN.,  then in the WHERE clause, have  "offer.id_sector2 > 0"

Answer (score 0):

After a deeper analysis, I have three records in table "offer", having id_category equal to "43" or "42": foreign keys of table "category".

Doing a join on table "category" won't be found any record having primary key equal to "43" or "42". In a nutshell, they won't be returned because of these key' absense.